# How to disable sorting on jQuery.DataTables init?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Is anyone tried [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index), when I bind(init) it to a `<table>`, data is sorted.

Is there anyway to disable the default sorting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to DataTabe's [reference manual](http://www.datatables.net/ref#aaSorting), this should work:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "order": [[3, "desc"]]
        });
    });
```